# event.offsetX в событии mousemove странно работает

Tags: javascript, css, css3, html5, slider

Пытаюсь сделать слайдер "до/после". Задумка такая: пользователь нажимает на "скроллер" (так я обозвал границу между 1-ой и 2-ой фотографиях). Срабатывает событие onmousedown, в котором срабатывает событие onmousemove, в котором я, при помощи event.offsetX, отслеживаю координаты мыши по оси X относительно всего слайдера. Проблема заключается в том, что если "скроллер" тянуть влево, то event.offsetX работает как-то странно: может сначала вернуть 130, а после 5, хотя должен был вернуть 129, т.к. я курсор сдвинул на 1px. Этот баг можно заметить, если передвигать "скроллер" медленно. Однако, если я буду тянуть "скроллер" вправо, то все работает нормально.

Почему event.offsetX так себя ведет и как это исправить?

```js
const scroller = document.getElementById('border'),
  firstImg = document.getElementById('first-img'),
  secondImg = document.getElementById('second-img');

secondImg.style.width = '600px';

scroller.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'w-resize';
  slider.onmousemove = (event) => {
    let x = event.offsetX;
    x > 1200 ? x = 1201 :
      x < 10 ? x = 10 : x = x;
    scroller.style.left = x + 'px';
    secondImg.style.width = (x - 1) + 'px';
  };
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'default';
  slider.onmousemove = (ev) => {
    return false;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
}

#slider {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 628px;
  border: 1px solid #333435;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2%;
  background-color: #1d1d1e;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first-img,
#second-img {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#border {
  width: 3px;
  height: calc(100% - 26px);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: w-resize;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 100;
  user-select: none;
}

img {
  user-select: none;
}

#black-line {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: 30px;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  left: calc(50% - 1.25px);
}
```

```html
<div id='slider'>
  <div id='first-img'>
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/BBB5cK5ykmoXbQob_9tEGEeMhM4=/0x292:2040x1360/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/13470451/jbareham_181120_ply0819_0060.jpg" alt="" draggable="false">
  </div>

  <div id='border'>
    <div id='black-line'></div>
  </div>

  <div id='second-img'>
    <img src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/09/15/5/og_og_1473921411216259234.jpg" alt="" draggable="false">
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/btfyn9h2/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать вместо `let x = event.offsetX;` это `let x = event.pageX - 25;`

Answer (score 1):

Прикольный слайдер. Если автор не против, я его где-нить заюзаю (на нон-комёршал проекте).

Всему виной `#slider`, точнее - его ширина. Событие `mousedown` теряется на этом элементе из-за разности в просчёте скорости изменения положения мыши и самого элемента, и откидывает (меняет ширину) `secondImg` до минимального значения. Получается "скачок". Если я правильно понял :)

Попробуйте так:

```js
const scroller  = document.getElementById('border'),
      firstImg  = document.getElementById('first-img'),
      secondImg = document.getElementById('second-img');
let flag = true; // флаг фиксирует состояние события mousedown

secondImg.style.width = '600px';

scroller.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  flag = true;
  window.onmousemove = true;
  scroller.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // отвязываемся от элемента
  document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'w-resize';
    window.onmousemove = (event) => { // слушаем событие по всему объекту window
      if (flag) {
        let x = event.offsetX;
        scroller.style.left = x + 'px';
        secondImg.style.width = x + 'px';
      }
    };
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  flag = false;
  scroller.style.pointerEvents = 'initial';
  document.documentElement.style.cursor = 'default';
  slider.onmousemove = (ev) => {
      return false;
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #212121;
}

#slider {
  margin: 25px;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 628px;
  border: 1px solid #333435;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2%;
  background-color: #1d1d1e;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#first-img, #second-img {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#border {
  width: 3px;
  height: calc(100% - 26px);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: w-resize;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 100;
  user-select: none;
}

img {
  user-select: none;
}

#black-line {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 2.5px;
  height: 30px;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  left: calc(50% - 1.25px);
}
```

```html
<div id = 'slider'>
  <div id = 'first-img'>
    <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/BBB5cK5ykmoXbQob_9tEGEeMhM4=/0x292:2040x1360/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/13470451/jbareham_181120_ply0819_0060.jpg" alt="" draggable="false">
  </div>
  
    <div id = 'border'>
      <div id = 'black-line'></div>
    </div>
  
  <div id = 'second-img'>
    <img src="https://cs8.pikabu.ru/post_img/2016/09/15/5/og_og_1473921411216259234.jpg" alt="" draggable="false">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ :)
Что касается использования слайдера - я не против)